# Найти самое короткое слово в массиве

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать javascript, не могу решить задачу, точнее не знаю как двигаться дальше. Нужно найти самое короткое слово, пожалуйста объясняйте, спасибо

```
const cars = ['bmv', 'mercedes', 'priora', 'toyota', 'nissan',];
```

Comment: А при чём тут js? Попробуй для начала написать *алгоритм* на русском языке

Comment: `console.log( cars.reduce((a,c) => (c.length < a.length ? a = c : a, a), cars[0]));`

Comment: @entithat оператор запятая - не нужен

Comment: @Igor, кстати да

Comment: И присваивание не нужно

Answer (score 4):

Способ для более продвинутых:

```js
const cars = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'aa', 'bb', 'c', 'b'];
console.log(cars.reduce((a, c) => c.length < a.length ? c : a, cars[0]));
```

Типичный способ решения для любого языка.

В переменную `min` записываем первый элемент массива (возможно он будет тем самым - нам нужным). Далее проходимся по каждому элементу массива и сравниваем его длинну с длинной слова в переменной `min`. Если мы нашли слово покороче - сохраняем его в `min`.

```js
const cars = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'aa', 'bb', 'c', 'b'];

let min = cars[0];
for (const car of cars) {
  if (car.length < min.length) {
    min = car;
  }
}

console.log(min);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы мне очень помогли